# how to calculate the magnetic force between a permanent magnet and a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Can anyone provide me with the equation of magnetic force between the permanent magnet and a magnetic field? Also kindly attach the reference journal link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a non-trivial problem that is usually being solved numerically because the magnetization of the material is non-linear and depends on the resulting field (unless the external field is weak). There are many software solutions available to simulate such problems. A really simple and easy to use tool is called FEMM: http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage. While it is limited to 2.5d geometries (the magnets and fields need to have either axial symmetry or be planar), it offers an easy to use interface to explore such problems. If you find it useful, you can upgrade to full 3d tools.

Comment: @CuriousOne That is a good and complete answer. It answers "Can anyone provide me with the equation..." with "No, nobody can, because it is difficult in some way/ But here is the alternative used in practice." Seems valid and useful to me.